# Controller or RestController

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

i'm new to jEE, and this is my first jEE code using spring. The code bellow is working fine. He just print the string index when i go to my localhost; and otherwise he print handling error.

My question is: Why this code isn't working anymore if I use `@Controller` instead of `@RestController`

I can't find any simple explanation in the docs from spring and I was hoping someone could explain this.

I have the feelings that a controller alone can't work without something like thymeleaf (I know if I were using thymeleaf the string index would be replaced by the index page from the ressources folder) where a RestController might be returning data as xml or json or something else.

Thanks

```
@RestController
public class HelloController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String error() {
        return "gestion erreur";
    }


    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

Comment: RestController is also a controller mixed with ResponseBody annotation. Please share what kind of error are you getting if using Controller.

Comment: Thats not javaee per se but Spring.

Comment: This might help: https://dzone.com/articles/how-i-used-decorator-pattern-to-solve-my-tech-issu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The job of `@Controller` is to create a Map of model object and find a view but `@RestController` simply return the object and object data is directly written into HTTP response as JSON or XML.

The `@Controller` is a common annotation which is used to mark a class as Spring MVC Controller while `@RestController` is a special controller used in RESTFul web services and the equivalent of `@Controller` + `@ResponseBody`.

If you want the same functionality of `@RestController` without using it you can use `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`.

```
@Controller
public class HelloController{

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. I was thinking right then, but I didn't knew about ResponseBody.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is how I get something: 
Part in @RestController:

@GetMapping("getSomething")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getSomething(){
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(service.getSomeTHing());
    }

Part in @Service:
public List<SomethingDTO> getSomething(){
        List<Something> somethings = sr.findAll();
        List<SomethingDTO> somethingsDTO = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Something s: somethings) {
            SomethingsDTO dto = new SomethingsDTO();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(p, dto);
            somethingsDTO.add(dto);
        }
        return somethingsDTO;
    }

And this is how I save something:

RestController:
@PostMapping("saveSomethings")
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveSomething(SomethingDTO something){
        if (something.getSomething() == "") {
            throw new EmptyFieldsException("No fields can be empty.");
        }
        if (glumac.getSomething().length() != 7)
            throw new InvalidLengthException("Length must be 7", somethings.getSomething().length());
        Integer idNewSomething = service.saveSomething(something);
        if (idNewSomething == -1)
            throw new SavingErrorException("Error while saving into database.");
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Success, new id is: "+idNewSomething);
        
    }

Service:

public int saveSomething(SomethingDTO something) {
        Something noviSomething = new Something();
        noviSomething.setSomething(something.getSomething());
        try {
            Something s = sr.save(newSomething);
            return s.getIdSomething();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;`enter code here`
        }   
    }
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).